# class is not working in wcf service class

Tags: asp.net, wcf

Public class is not working in wcf services. I have created one another public class and use into my service.svc but class is not accessible. Please see the following code.

ITest.cs

```
namespace TestProject.Services
{
  [ServiceContract]
  public interface ITest
  {
    [ServiceContract]
    public interface ITest
    {
        [OperationContract]
        DataTable SelectData(string sSectionName);
    }
 }
 }
```

ITest.svc.cs

```
 namespace TestProject.Services
 {
   public class Test: ITest
    {
      public DataTable SelectData(string sSectionName)
       {
        //do some work

       }
     }
   }
```

Ohter New class

```
Public class connection
{
   public int sum(int i, int b)
   {
     return i+b;
    }
 }
```

My connection class is not accessible in ITest.svc.cs. Please help

Comment: Please create constructor for that class, then try

Comment: try using the [namespace].connection

Comment: @user256103 - if a constructor is not provided in the code, the compiler will generate a default parameterless constructor.  Adding a constructor explicitly will not resolve the OP's issue.

Comment: Why do you have a nested interface?  Or was that a typo?

Answer (score 0):

Try rewriting connection as such:

```
 namespace TestProject.Services
 {
     Public class connection
     {
        public int sum(int i, int b)
        {
          return i+b;
        }
     }
}
```